# Salesforce API to retrieve files with size 2GB

Tags: api, developer-console, contentversion, largedatavolumes

So, we upload files approximately with size of 2GB in salesforce cases in lightning. What would be the best way to receive it? (Download through api).

Currently, I use `/ContentVersion` endpoint to get the file contents and write them to a file as a binary stream.

Are there any limitations or best practices I am missing out on?
Is there any way to retrieve the file in chunks?